# Probability / Statistics - Event Occurring Only Once

Tags: statistics, probability

If I have a 1/10 chance of winning a race. What chance do I have of winning exactly one race if I take part in three separate races? My chances of winning are 1/10 for each race. I have been told the answer is 24.3% but I have no idea how this number was calculated no matter how hard I try. The closest I get is 27.1% which is  1 - (9/10)^3

Comment: This may also be a helpful read, as this deals with a similar problem (and has that formula I was talking about): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/684899/calculate-the-probability-of-an-event-occurring-at-least-x-times-over-n-trials

Comment: Thanks I found things like this last night but I struggled to understand these equations

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about probability / mathematics and not directly about programming / coding / software algorithms / programming tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three possible favorable paths:

1. Win first race and lose the next two, with probability (1/10)x(9/10)x(9/10)
2. Lose first one, win second one and lose also third one, with probability (9/10)x(1/10)x(9/10)
3. Lose first two and win third one, with probability (9/10)x(9/10)x(1/10)

Each favorable path has probability 81/1000. Adding them up, you get 243/1000=0.243

Comment: Man I feel stupid now. I must have tried every other combination and got lost in the process. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really the place to ask these kinds of questions, but in this case you could think of it as taking each of the different combinations (win-lose-lose, lose-win-lose, and lose-lose-win) and combining them like so: 0.1*0.9*0.9 + 0.9*0.1*0.9 + 0.9*0.9*0.1 (replace win with 0.1 or 1/10 and lose with 0.9, which is 1-0.1).

(By the way, there is a more general formula for this situation, but I can't remember it at the moment.)

Comment: Thank you, I feel so stupid now. I placed the question in Quora first but answers are slow and I noticed other people had asked math questions on this platform previously. This will translate back into some code i'm writing